# Hibernate merge does not do anything

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an `EntityVO` class, which is mapped to a `Persistence Unit 'A'`.I cannot edit this `EntityVO` as well as `Persistence Unit A`, because it is packed inside dependency jar. Therefore I created a `CustomEntityVO` and mapped it to `Persistence unit B`.

Now the problem is, if I am trying to merge the `CustomEntityVO` using `entity manager of B`, its not doing anything nor throwing any exception.

This is how I am trying to merge:

```
this.DAO.detach(customEntityVO);
customEntityVO= this.DAO.merge(customEntityVO);
this.DAO.merge(customEntityVO);
this.DAO.flush(customEntityVO);
```

I have spring @Transactional(readOnly=false) annotation also on the method, but update is not happening.
I am not getting any clue why.

Comment: Here all of the customEntityVOs and DAOs  look like they all belong to one persistence unit. I mean you call the same DAO and same customEntityVO. You should fetch the customEntityVO from persistence unit A, then assign it (or convert it) to the customEntityVO from persistence unit B, then do whatever you want! Persist, merge, update, delete whatever

Comment: @OnurBaştürk: No,I cannot fetch customEntityVO from persistence unit A, as customEntityVO(also the DAO) is mapped only to persistence unit B .